# Is it possible to put android resources folder to separate android library project with Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

I would like to put android resources folder to separate android library project. So I want to save my time due to of the need to rebuild the project to make android resources id's regenerate.
I am using Xamarin.Android and Visual Studio.

Comment: Yes you can move images in drawables, but i dont think moving out the layout or others is possible.